# Throttling limit with Docusign User Management api

Tags: docusignapi

What is the technical limit for docusign users? is there any chance we can expect 1M users from {docusigndomain}/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/users

we need these details to implement throttling logic to handle huge volume of records

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is use the "paging" feature that lets you get 100 records at a time. You do that by specifying:

&count=100&start_position=100 (200, 300 etc..)

And looping until you get no more records.

> is there any chance we can expect 1M users from

Theoretically, yes. Most accounts won't have more than 50 users, but some large enterprise accounts can have as many as they want.

Please see https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/users/users/list/ for details.